# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to add a repo using terminal. While adding that, I got an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I tried installing that module using various commands like :

```
pip3 install apt_pkg
```

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

```
sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall
```

Then if I tried to add that repo, the same error appeared.

The python versions I have is :

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.9
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

These are the versions I have in terminal. In IDLE, I have 3.5

What else shall I do to install that package apt_pkg???

Comment: Try running `pip` like this: `python3 pip install apt_pkg` and then run your script using `python3`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949591/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-installing-deadsnakes-repository