# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' installing deadsnakes repository

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apt

I want to install Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm currently on Python 3.8) from the deadsnakes repository with the following set of commands I found on the internet:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10
```

But I got the error `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`.

More net research led me to this set of commands at ["ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'" appears in various commands - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242009/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-appears-in-various-commands):

```
sudo apt remove python3-apt
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install python3-apt
```

Other web sources said the same thing, so I did that, but I still get the error message when I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`.

Then I found [How to Fix 'add-apt-repository command not found' on Ubuntu & Debian - phoenixNAP](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/add-apt-repository-command-not-found-ubuntu), which advised this set of commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt update
```

so I did that, but when I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` I now get this error message:

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I have found some web links that show a wide variety of solutions with earlier versions of Python.  I'm currently on Python 3.8.

Before I do anything more I want to ask what is the best way to solve the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` error message when trying to install the deadsnakes repository to install Python 3.10, given the number of possible solutions I have seen.

Thanks very much.

Comment: maybe first you should check if you have `add-apt-repository` and eventually use `/full/path/to/add-apt-repository`. You may have problem with `apt_pkg` because you run `remove python3-apt` and later `install python3-apt` - as for me it was very wrong idea.

Comment: I use Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) and I can't test it with Ubunut 18.04 but I have the same command with two names `add-apt-repository` and `apt-add-repository` - maybe you have `apt-add-repository` instead of `add-apt-repository`

Comment: I'm not sure but older Ubuntu could use `Python 3.6` to run system functions - and if you even had `Python 3.8` then it still could need to install `apt` modules in `Python 3.6`

Comment: BTW: Python `3.10` is very fresh version and some modules may not work with this version so better wait few months and still use `3.8`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I will try your first two ideas.  If I can't get it to install I can build from source, but I would like to use deadsnakes if I can.

Comment: I have /usr/bin/add-apt-repository and  /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz

Comment: I also use `deadsnakes` but I add it using `GUI` - program `synaptic` or `mintupdate` (it is update-manager in Linux Mint which displays icon in status bar  when there are updates)

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead. I realize the question involves Python, but it's not related to code that you've written, so the question is not about programming per se.

Comment: Did you get the steps mixed up? The first error is about `add-apt-repository`, but the link you mentioned is about `apt_pkg`.

Comment: I bet the root problem is that you changed the symlink `/usr/bin/python3` to point to `python3.8` instead of `python3.6`. You're not supposed to do that on Ubuntu since it's a core system component. [This existing question seems to be a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229095/301745).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This worked for me:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

The 38 in the filename above can be different for you.

Comment: I had same error message in a different situation, but the first-line alone fixed it for me thanks

Comment: for me it was the latest Ubuntu so I had to do:
 `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  apt_pkg.so`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the python_apt comes from the Ubuntu repo, offering python-apt for the default python 3.8, while you are running python 3.10. Copying the .so from Python 3.8 is not a clean solution. You are missing the expected apt_inst here causing recent Ansible libraries to fail. My approach was to recompile the python-apt library from python 3.10, this recreates the relevant python libraries:

```
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt
cd python-apt && apt build-dep ./ -y && python3 setup.py build && python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

No amount of fiddling with `apt install --reinstall` fixed this for me, which in my case is due to `usr/lib/python3` not being included in apt-python's `sys.path`. (I presumably broke this by installing python from source.)

As a hack of last resort, I forced `/usr/bin/apt-listchanges` into finding `apt_pkg.so` by modifying it:

```
  cat /usr/bin/apt-listchanges
  (...)
  import sys, os, os.path
  import functools
+ sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
  import apt_pkg
  (...)
```

This is gross, but I am only trying to fix apt well enough to uninstall everything and do a `dist-upgrade`.